# Print a sequence of letters

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, sequence

How do I print a sequence of letters with PHP, without using 'for'? It needs to be something like this:

[image: print a sequence of letters]

I have a code like this:

```
<?php

$a = 'a';
$n = 50;
$i = 0;
$k = 0;

while ( $i < $n ) {
    echo $a." ".'<p></p>';
    for ($k =0; $k<=$i; $k++) { 
        echo $a." ";
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

But I don't need 'for', maybe something with 'while', 'if' or 'foreach'.
Ideas?

Comment: The code you have works fine. what are you asking?

Comment: Your code doesn't work?

Comment: You can use str_repeat instead of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to use a second while loop:

```
$a = 'a';
$n = 50;
$i = 0;

while ($i < $n) {
    $k = -1;
    $str = "";
    while ($k < $i) {
        $str .= " $a";
        $k++;
    }
    echo "$str<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/neDg1)

Another option could be using [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
while ( $i < $n ) echo str_repeat($a, ++$i) . "<br>";
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/IhgEl)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

print
implode(
    "\n",
    array_map(
        function($n) {
            return str_repeat('a', $n);
        },
        range(1,10)
    )
);
```

Output:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way too, thanks for all the answers!

```
<?php

$i=0; 
$j=50; 
while($i < $j ) {
    $j=50; 
    $k=0;
    while($k <= $i){
        echo 'a';
        ++$k;
    }
    echo "<p></p>";
    $i++;
}
```

And it's easy to understand if you are new to the coding world.

Comment: No need for the second assignment to `$j`.

Answer (score 0):

The following are equivalent.

for within for:

```
<?php
for($i=1, $n=10; $i<=$n; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++) {
        echo 'a';
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

for and str_repeat:

```
<?php
for($i=1, $n=10; $i<=$n; $i++)
    echo str_repeat('a', $i), "\n";
```

foreach with a range and str_repeat:

```
<?php
foreach(range(1, 10) as $n)
    echo str_repeat('a', $n), "\n";
```

Output (for each of the snippets):

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```